# A default document is not configured for the requested URL

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Creating a new section to my MVC site called "Reports".

Created a simple controller and starter Index view.

If I try to browse to ".../Reports/Index" things work fine.  I am greeted with my page.

If I try to browse to ".../Reports", I get the message listed in the title.  (...default document not configured...)

When I try the same with another section like ".../Customers", I get my index page... so, I think my routing is setup properly.

Here is my RouteConfig just in case:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { 
                controller = "Home", 
                action = "Index", 
                id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

I must be missing something simple related to the new reports page, but I just can't see it.  I need some fresh eyes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had another folder name "Reports" at the top level of the directory tree in my project.  I had planned to, well, put the reports in there.  Anyway, MVC did not know which folder to route to, since there were to folders name "Reports" in my project.

Just to test the fix I renamed the report storage location to "Report" (dropped the "s"), ran again and tada... MVC is happy again.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the issue was because you had a SQL server with SQL Server Reporting enabled, as it will take over the Reports folder name. 
As The answerer pointed out if you rename the folder it avoids SQL server Reportings use of the alias